# Visual Studio edit view corrupt for xaml and Winforms design views

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, winforms, xaml

I'm looking for help on a bad editing experience. As you can see in the image below, when I try to edit an xaml file, the edit windows are corrupted. This is for a WPF project.

[EDIT] I have since discovered the same issue with Winforms design views.

[image]

The screen review and source code are in the left corner, overlaying the tabs. There is nothing in the preview window even though I have defined a window and some controls. There are no scroll bars or other editor controls. The mouse doesn't work in this window. The view and problems are the same if I dock it back in the main window.

I've updated to the latest Visual Studio (VS22 17.9.5 64-bit Community). I've checked for new display drivers and I have no display hardware acceleration.

The file is editable in Blend, but this is a difficult workflow when I'm using Copilot to decorate the controls with styles and resources.I have to switch back and forth between Blend and VS, and can't do it inline.

Comment: How are your GPU drivers? Also, you should do a RAM check (`memtestx86`, etc).

Comment: As mentioned above, I've checked for new display drivers (it's a Surface laptop with integrated Intel GPU only).
I would expect memory issues to be inconsistent, as the use of memory is dynamic and never the same. This issue can be reproduced on demand every time, after reboots and with different activities happening in the background.

Comment: You could try a few troubleshooting steps.1.Restart Visual Studio 2.Reset Window Layout: You can do this by going to Window > Reset Window Layout. 3.Check for Visual Studio Updates: Sometimes, bugs and display issues are fixed in newer versions. 4.Create a new WPF project in Visual Studio and see if the issue persists. 5.You can reset Visual Studio user settings by going to Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings. 6.You can disable an extension by going to Extensions > Manage Extensions and then disabling or uninstalling extensions.

Comment: You can also try following these steps to enable the XAML designer (requires restarting Visual Studio) and see if that helps:
Tools => Options => XAML Designer => General => Check Enable XAML Designer(requires restart of Visual Studio)

Comment: Thanks @HuiLiu-MSFT

1.Restart Visual Studio - check
2.Reset Window Layout - check
3.Check for Visual Studio Updates - check
4.Create a new WPF project in Visual Studio and see if the issue persists - check
5.You can reset Visual Studio user settings by... - check
6.You can disable an extension by going to Extensions.... - check

Problem still persists  :( 

I opened the project on another machine and it displays correctly. It's the same VS version but there is clearly some other difference somewhere. It's a very different machine with a Geforce graphics card and other differences

Comment: Since you mentioned that the other machine has a different graphics card, it's possible that the issue is related to graphics settings or drivers on your machine. 1.Review the display settings on your machine, including screen resolution, scaling, and multiple display configurations. 2.Ensure that your machine has enough resources (CPU, memory, disk space) available to run Visual Studio smoothly. 
3.Temporarily disable or adjust the settings of any security software installed on your original machine

Comment: Does this problem exist with other software applications?If not, you can also try some of the following steps.
1.You can try running Visual Studio in safe mode(open the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio and type devenv /safemode) to see if the issue persists. 
2.Create a new user profile on your original machine and see if the issue persists when using Visual Studio under the new profile.
3.consider uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio on your original machine.

Comment: I consider myself a virtual XAML expert (UWP and WPF), but could never get the hang of Blend; and using it at the same time as VS seems inconceivable (to me)

Comment: It's looking like the issue is coincidental with updating Visual Studio, and not related to XAML directly. It was the start of a new project and I wanted to be up to date. It was also my first XAML project, and the two coincided. I just opened a Winforms project and got the same issue with the corrupted design view.

I'll update the title as this is misleading after my latest investigations.
Thanks for all of the help, the suggestions are still relevant and I'll keep trying to resolve.

Comment: Hi,@batvink.Based on your description, it may be a problem with Visual Studio. You could try reinstalling Visual Studio to see if it helps.